# Amazon Query String not working with Launchy

Tags: query-string

I use the opensource program Launchy for literally everything on my computer.

I use the plugin "Weby" which allows me to search direct results in websites (google, youtube etc). I always used to use one for Amazon but recently it's stopped working.

My query string is:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=%1

Which is the normal search query for anything you type in Amazon (The %1 being what I typed into Launchy). This is how all my other weby links work so not sure why this one has stopped.

When I try use this is redirects to:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/ref=nb_sb_noss_null

If you go to Amazon and type "test" you get:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=test

Which is exactly what my %1 is doing for all my other weby links.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but if only for the benefit of people googling this, here's a solution. I couldn't get Amazon search to work with Weby and solved this issue using Runner. Yes Runner can accept URLs instead of executables.

Put this in the Program field of your Runner task (and nothing in arguments):

https://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias%3Dapps&field-keywords=$$

If you want to be able to scope your query by department, use this:

https://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias%3D$$&field-keywords=$$

Then in Launchy

amazon [tab] books [tab] the amazon way

This also works on amazon.co.uk, .fr, .de - just change the extension in the URLs above.

Comment: That's great and works, for .co.uk it is:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=$$

But that also now works fine in Weby with:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=%1